# Hidden features of Haskell

Tags: haskell

What are the lesser-known but useful features of the Haskell programming language. (I understand the language itself is lesser-known, but work with me. Even explanations of the simple things in Haskell, like defining the Fibonacci sequence with one line of code, will get upvoted by me.)

- Try to limit answers to the Haskell core
- One feature per answer
- Give an example and short description of the feature, not just a link to documentation
- Label the feature using bold title as the first line

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/should-hidden-features-of-x-be-removed-closed-locked, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57226/should-we-have-a-list-of-x-close-reason, and related Meta posts

Comment: Do "simple things" count as hidden features of Haskell?  Is this question a discussion list of every Haskell feature?

Comment: Ok why is this being closed when there is what 103 some other questions named "Hidden feature of *" is not closed, come on!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**My brain just exploded**

If you try to compile this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data Foo = forall a. Foo a
ignorefoo f = 1 where Foo a = f
```

You will get this error message:

```
$ ghc Foo.hs

Foo.hs:3:22:
    My brain just exploded.
    I can't handle pattern bindings for existentially-quantified constructors.
    Instead, use a case-expression, or do-notation, to unpack the constructor.
    In the binding group for
        Foo a
    In a pattern binding: Foo a = f
    In the definition of `ignorefoo':
        ignorefoo f = 1
                    where
                        Foo a = f
```

Comment: I think the following should still give this error:
ignorefoo f = 1
  where (Foo a) = f

Comment: Ah, you're right, **that**'s what makes GHC's brain explode.  I didn't *think* they had fixed it yet, but I couldn't make my simple example break...

Comment: @ephemient They can't fix it, because "fixing" it would break Haskell's type system. Think of it this way: everything in Haskell has a type. In the line `where Foo a = f`, what is the type of `a`?

Answer (score 40):

**User-defined control structures**

Haskell has no shorthand ternary operator.  The built-in `if`-`then`-`else` is always ternary, and is an expression (imperative languages tend to have `?:`=expression, `if`=statement).  If you want, though,

```
True ? x = const x
False ? _ = id
```

will define `(?)` to be the ternary operator:

```
(a ? b $ c)  ==  (if a then b else c)
```

You'd have to resort to macros in most other languages to define your own short-circuiting logical operators, but Haskell is a fully lazy language, so it just works.

```
-- prints "I'm alive! :)"
main = True ? putStrLn "I'm alive! :)" $ error "I'm dead :("
```

Comment: Defined that way I need to put a or b in parenthesis when with if I don't. Can infix help here?

Comment: @gorlum0: Sure, just give it a higher fixity than `$`, e.g. `infixr 1 ?` or something like that.

Answer (score 28):

**Hoogle**

Hoogle is your friend. I admit, it's not part of the "core", so `cabal install hoogle`

Now you know how "if you're looking for a higher-order function, it's already there" ([ephemient's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211216/hidden-features-of-haskell/213436#213436)). But how do you find that function? With hoogle!

```
$ hoogle "Num a => [a] -> a"
Prelude product :: Num a => [a] -> a
Prelude sum :: Num a => [a] -> a

$ hoogle "[Maybe a] -> [a]"
Data.Maybe catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]

$ hoogle "Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]"
Prelude sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]

$ hoogle "[a] -> [b] -> (a -> b -> c) -> [c]"
Prelude zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

The hoogle-google programmer is not able to write his programs on paper by himself the same way he does with the help of the computer. But he and the machine together are a forced not* to be reckoned with.

Btw, if you liked hoogle be sure to check out hlint!

Comment: Hoogle is also available online at http://haskell.org/hoogle/

Comment: This is the best API searching tool that I have ever come accross. Because most of the time you know roughly what you are searching for; as in what it should do. This lets you search for anything that looks like that.

Answer (score 22):

**Free Theorems**

Phil Wadler introduced us to the notion of a [free theorem](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.38.9875) and we've been abusing them in Haskell ever since.

These wonderful artifacts of Hindley-Milner-style type systems help out with equational reasoning by using parametricity to tell you about what a function *will not* do.

For instance, there are two laws that every instance of Functor should satisfy:

1. forall f g. fmap f . fmap g = fmap (f . g)
2. fmap id = id

But, the free theorem tells us we need not bother proving the first one, but given the second it comes for 'free' just from the type signature!

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

You need to be a bit careful with laziness, but this is partially covered in the original paper, and in Janis Voigtlaender's [more recent paper](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=982962.964010) on free theorems in the presence of `seq`.

Comment: +1 I totally did not know about this but it is really cool; why isn't this higher. That removes alot of proof work if you can derive a result straight from the type signature. Reading about it now.

Answer (score 20):

**Shorthand for a common list operation**

The following are equivalent:

```
concat $ map f list
concatMap f list
list >>= f
```

### Edit

Since more details were requested...

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

`concat` takes a list of lists and concatenates them into a single list.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

`map` maps a function over a list.

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
```

`concatMap` is equivalent to `(.) concat . map`: map a function over a list, and concatenate the results.

```
class Monad m where
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
    return :: a -> m a
```

A `Monad` has a *bind* operation, which is called `>>=` in Haskell (or its sugared `do`-equivalent).  List, aka `[]`, is a `Monad`.  If we substitute `[]` for `m` in the above:

```
instance Monad [] where
    (>>=) :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
    return :: a -> [a]
```

What's the natural thing for the `Monad` operations to do on a list?  We have to satisfy the monad laws,

```
return a >>= f           ==  f a
ma >>= (\a -> return a)  ==  ma
(ma >>= f) >>= g         ==  ma >>= (\a -> f a >>= g)
```

You can verify that these laws hold if we use the implementation

```
instance Monad [] where
    (>>=) = concatMap
    return = (:[])

return a >>= f  ==  [a] >>= f  ==  concatMap f [a]  ==  f a
ma >>= (\a -> return a)  ==  concatMap (\a -> [a]) ma  ==  ma
(ma >>= f) >>= g  ==  concatMap g (concatMap f ma)  ==  concatMap (concatMap g . f) ma  ==  ma >>= (\a -> f a >>= g)
```

This is, in fact, the behavior of `Monad []`.  As a demonstration,

```
double x = [x,x]
main = do
    print $ map double [1,2,3]
        -- [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]
    print . concat $ map double [1,2,3]
        -- [1,1,2,2,3,3]
    print $ concatMap double [1,2,3]
        -- [1,1,2,2,3,3]
    print $ [1,2,3] >>= double
        -- [1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

Comment: Should I split this into multiple answers?

Comment: Would you rather get 1 up vote (or possibly 1 down for not following the question's rules) or 1 up vote for each feature?

Comment: Well then.  Here comes the flood...

Comment: i don't quite follow the way this works - can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: List is an instance of Monad.  >>= for lists concatenates.

Comment: That should be (>>=) = flip concatMap.

Comment: @Martijn: Right.  I guess nobody else noticed that `(>>=) = concatMap` doesn't typecheck ;)

Comment: After getting a bit more familiarity with it, I think the List Monad is a bit problematic...  The complaint is that this isn't the only possible way to make a List follow the Monadic laws.  Note the answer says "if we use the implementation" - but why should we be forced to use this implementation?  Another valid implementation would be similar to the Maybe Monad, where an empty list is equivalent to Nothing and a non-empty list is equivalent to Just first element...  Maybe not the best example, but I think the point remains.

Comment: The List Monad definitely isn't the only possible or reasonable implementation to satisfy the Monad rules, but it's the one that's documented in the Haskell report, and is the most useful.  If it worked like `Maybe`, `[x | x <- xs]` and `do x <- xs; return x` would no longer be equivalent.

Answer (score 19):

**Nestable multiline comments**.

```
{- inside a comment,
     {- inside another comment, -}
still commented! -}
```

Comment: How about nestable single-line comments? ;-)

Answer (score 19):

Generalized algebraic data types.  Here's an example interpreter where the type system lets you cover all the cases:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module Exp
where

data Exp a where
  Num  :: (Num a) => a -> Exp a
  Bool :: Bool -> Exp Bool
  Plus :: (Num a) => Exp a -> Exp a -> Exp a
  If   :: Exp Bool -> Exp a -> Exp a -> Exp a 
  Lt   :: (Num a, Ord a) => Exp a -> Exp a -> Exp Bool
  Lam  :: (a -> Exp b) -> Exp (a -> b)   -- higher order abstract syntax
  App  :: Exp (a -> b) -> Exp a -> Exp b
 -- deriving (Show) -- failse

eval :: Exp a -> a
eval (Num n)      = n
eval (Bool b)     = b
eval (Plus e1 e2) = eval e1 + eval e2
eval (If p t f)   = eval $ if eval p then t else f
eval (Lt e1 e2)   = eval e1 < eval e2
eval (Lam body)   = \x -> eval $ body x
eval (App f a)    = eval f $ eval a

instance Eq a => Eq (Exp a) where
  e1 == e2 = eval e1 == eval e2

instance Show (Exp a) where
  show e = "<exp>" -- very weak show instance

instance (Num a) => Num (Exp a) where
  fromInteger = Num
  (+) = Plus
```

Comment: +1, A full dependently typed programming language like Agda is quite hard to understand/work with (at least to me :-). But GADTs already bring some of the big benefits of dependent types to Haskell, without adding too much of a mental burden for my brain.

Comment: In the Num instance do you mean "fromInteger = Num . fromInteger"?

Answer (score 18):

**Patterns in top-level bindings**

```
five :: Int
Just five = Just 5

a, b, c :: Char
[a,b,c] = "abc"
```

How cool is that! Saves you that call to `fromJust` and `head` every now and then.

Answer (score 17):

**Optional Layout**

You can use explicit braces and semicolons instead of whitespace (aka layout) to delimit blocks.

```
let {
      x = 40;
      y = 2
     } in
 x + y
```

... or equivalently...

```
let { x = 40; y = 2 } in x + y
```

... instead of ...

```
let x = 40
    y = 2
 in x + y
```

Because layout is not required, Haskell programs can be straightforwardly produced by other programs.

Answer (score 16):

**Operator Fixity**

You can use the [infix, infixl or infixr](http://haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html#sect4.4.2) keywords to define operators associativity and precedence. Example taken from the [reference](http://www.zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputsyntax/fixityQdeclaration_reference.html):

```
main = print (1 +++ 2 *** 3)

infixr  6 +++
infixr  7 ***,///

(+++) :: Int -> Int -> Int
a +++ b = a + 2*b

(***) :: Int -> Int -> Int
a *** b = a - 4*b

(///) :: Int -> Int -> Int
a /// b = 2*a - 3*b
Output: -19
```

The number (0 to 9) after the infix allows you to define the precedence of the operator, being 9 the strongest. Infix means no associativity, whereas infixl associates left and infixr associates right.

This allows you to define complex operators to do high level operations written as simple expressions.

Note that you can also use binary functions as operators if you place them between backticks:

```
main = print (a `foo` b)

foo :: Int -> Int -> Int
foo a b = a + b
```

And as such, you can also define precedence for them:

```
infixr 4 `foo`
```

Comment: Aren't they backticks, actually?

    Prelude> print (a  `foo` b)
    6

Comment: Yes, those should be backticks.  Are there really people who consider this to be a hidden feature?

Comment: Changed ticks to backticks, my mistake. And whether it is considered a hidden feature or not, it depends on how much knowledge you have on the language. Sorry if you didnt like it.

Comment: "Infix means no associativity" -- how is that possible? If I do `infix  6 +++` then how does `1 +++ 2 +++ 3` get evaluated? It seems to me it must be either `(1 +++ 2) +++ 3` or `1 +++ (2 +++ 3)`. Even those might evaluate to the same thing, Haskell must pick one or the other to actually *do*, right?

Comment: Precedence parsing error
        cannot mix `+++' [infix 6] and `+++' [infix 6] in the same infix expression

Answer (score 16):

**`seq` and `($!)` [only evaluate](http://users.aber.ac.uk/afc/stricthaskell.html#seq) enough to check that something is not bottom.**

The following program will only print "there".

```
main = print "hi " `seq` print "there"
```

For those unfamiliar with Haskell, Haskell is non-strict in general, meaning that an argument to a function is only evaluated if it is needed.

For example, the following prints "ignored" and terminates with success.

```
main = foo (error "explode!")
  where foo _ = print "ignored"
```

`seq` is known to change that behavior by evaluating to bottom if its first argument is bottom.

For example:

```
main = error "first" `seq` print "impossible to print"
```

... or equivalently, without infix ...

```
main = seq (error "first") (print "impossible to print")
```

... will blow up with an error on "first".  It will never print "impossible to print".

So it might be a little surprising that even though `seq` is strict, it won't evaluate something the way eager languages evaluate.  In particular, it won't try to force all the positive integers in the following program.  Instead, it will check that `[1..]` isn't bottom (which can be found immediately), print "done", and exit.

```
main = [1..] `seq` print "done"
```

Comment: What do you mean 'not bottom'?

Comment: Added an explanation.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Basically, "bottom" is any undefined value like the result of calling error.  Something that loops forever is also called bottom.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that clears it up! 

How can it check that something loops forever? Isn't that the halting problem, which is impossible to decide?

Comment: Also, doesn't [1..] loop forever? (It at least generates an infinite amount of integers

Comment: I believe that if something loops forever, calling seq on it will also loop forever.  [1..] generates an infinite number of integers.  Due to laziness, they won't actually get computed until you try to grab one, and seq doesn't do that.

Comment: [1..] simply evaluates to 1:[2..], that is, the list that starts with 1, followed by another list.  It only loops forever if you try to get to the end of the list.

Comment: Also, GHC does detect (some) infinite loops -- you can define "loop = loop" just fine, but if you try to print the value of "loop", it will error "<<loop>>".

Comment: more reading about the value bottom: http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Bottom

Answer (score 15):

**Avoiding parentheses**

The `(.)` and `($)` functions in `Prelude` have very convenient fixities, letting you avoid parentheses in many places.  The following are equivalent:

```
f (g (h x))
f $ g $ h x
f . g $ h x
f . g . h $ x
```

`flip` helps too, the following are equivalent:

```
map (\a -> {- some long expression -}) list
flip map list $ \a ->
    {- some long expression -}
```

Comment: I prefer parentheses. They are more explicit.

Comment: I prefer to eliminate parentheses wherever possible, even when I'm working in less convenient languages like C (under the assumption that everybody reading my code *must know* all operator precedences).  It's a matter of taste.

Comment: pointless notation is real expressive once you get used to it. It's just a list of sequential verbs.

Comment: I come from Java so not using parentheses in Haskell is a pleasure.

Comment: Parentheses are just the right symbol for nesting. Why look for something else?

Answer (score 15):

**Pretty guards**

`Prelude` defines `otherwise = True`, making complete guard conditions read very naturally.

```
fac n
  | n < 1     = 1
  | otherwise = n * fac (n-1)
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, GHC actually treats `otherwise` subtly different from `True`: Using `True`, you get a warning about how you didn't cover all the possible cases; with `otherwise` you don't.

Comment: @MatrixFrog I get no warning with `True`, but if I do `not False`, `True || False`, `True || True`, `True || undefined`, etc. it warns. (GHC 6.12.3, with -Wall compile option).

Comment: @Longpoke they probably went ahead and did the same thing for `True` that they had previously done for `otherwise`. I would say it's probably good to continue using `otherwise` though, just because it reads a little nicer.

Answer (score 15):

**C-Style Enumerations**

Combining top-level pattern matching and arithmetic sequences gives us a handy way to define consecutive values:

```
foo : bar : baz : _ = [100 ..]    -- foo = 100, bar = 101, baz = 102
```

Answer (score 13):

**Readable function composition**

`Prelude` defines `(.)` to be mathematical function composition; that is, `g . f` first applies `f`, then applies `g` to the result.

If you `import Control.Arrow`, the following are equivalent:

```
g . f
f >>> g
```

`Control.Arrow` provides an `instance Arrow (->)`, and this is nice for people who don't like to read function application backwards.

Comment: Note also that `(<<<) = (.)` :)

Answer (score 11):

`let 5 = 6 in ...` is valid Haskell.

Comment: Does  let 5 = 6  ...  have any effect?

Comment: Its the constant pattern `5` matched against the value `6`, but since let-bindings are completely lazy, the match will never be attempted.

Answer (score 10):

**Infinite Lists**

Since you mentioned fibonacci, there is a very elegant way of [generating fibonacci numbers](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html#tut-lazy-patterns) from an infinite list like this:

```
fib@(1:tfib)    = 1 : 1 : [ a+b | (a,b) <- zip fib tfib ]
```

The @ operator allows you to use pattern matching on the 1:tfib structure while still referring to the whole pattern as fib.

Note that the comprehension list enters an infinite recursion, generating an infinite list. However, you can request elements from it or operate them, as long as you request a finite amount:

```
take 10 fib
```

You can also apply an operation to all elements before requesting them:

```
take 10 (map (\x -> x+1) fib)
```

This is thanks to Haskell's lazy evaluation of parameters and lists.

Comment: Syntax extensions in GHC let you write this now: fib = 1 : 1 : [ a+b | a <- fib | b <- tail fib ]; however I'd write it 1:1:zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)

Comment: Your first example actually demonstrates an even more hidden feature of Haskell: you can use full patterns when defining values/functions!

Answer (score 9):

**Flexible specification of module imports and exports**

Importing and exporting is nice.

```
module Foo (module Bar, blah)  -- this is module Foo, export everything that Bar expored, plus blah

import qualified Some.Long.Name as Short
import Some.Long.Name (name)  -- can import multiple times, with different options

import Baz hiding (blah)  -- import everything from Baz, except something named 'blah'
```

Answer (score 8):

**If you're looking for a list or higher-order function, it's already there**

There's sooo many convenience and higher-order functions in the standard library.

```
-- factorial can be written, using the strict HOF foldl':
fac n = Data.List.foldl' (*) 1 [1..n]
-- there's a shortcut for that:
fac n = product [1..n]
-- and it can even be written pointfree:
fac = product . enumFromTo 1
```

Answer (score 8):

**Equational Reasoning**

Haskell, being purely functional allows you to read an equal sign as a real equal sign (in the absence of non-overlapping patterns).

This allows you to substitute definitions directly into code, and in terms of optimization gives a lot of leeway to the compiler about when stuff happens.

A good example of this form of reasoning can  be found here:

http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-March/058603.html

This also manifests itself nicely in the form of laws or RULES pragmas expected for valid members of an instance, for instance the Monad laws:

1. returrn a >>= f == f a
2. m >>= return == m
3. (m >>= f) >>= g == m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)

can often be used to simplify monadic code.

Answer (score 6):

**Enhanced pattern matching**

- Lazy patterns
- Irrefutable patterns

  ```
  let ~(Just x) = someExpression
  ```

See [pattern matching](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html)

Comment: This gives a compiler error: Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t = Maybe t

Answer (score 6):

**Parallel list comprehension**

(Special GHC-feature)

```
  fibs = 0 : 1 : [ a + b | a <- fibs | b <- tail fibs ]
```

Answer (score 6):

**Laziness**

Ubiquitous laziness means you can do things like define

```
fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

But it also provides us with a lot of more subtle benefits in terms of syntax and reasoning.

For instance, due to strictness ML has to deal with the [value restriction](http://www.strangelights.com/fsharp/wiki/default.aspx/FSharpWiki/ValueRestriction.html), and is very careful to track circular let bindings, but in Haskell, we can let every let be recursive and have no need to distinguish between `val` and `fun`. This removes a major syntactic wart from the language.

This indirectly gives rise to our lovely `where` clause, because we can safely move computations that may or may not be used out of the main control flow and let laziness deal with sharing the results.

We can replace (almost) all of those ML style functions that need to take () and return a value, with just a lazy computation of the value. There are reasons to avoid doing so from time to time to avoid leaking space with [CAFs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constant_applicative_form), but such cases are rare.

Finally, it permits unrestricted eta-reduction (`\x -> f x` can be replaced with f). This makes combinator oriented programming for things like parser combinators much more pleasant than working with similar constructs in a strict language.

This helps you when reasoning about programs in point-free style, or about rewriting them into point-free style and reduces argument noise.

Comment: The value restriction link is now dead.

Answer (score 5):

**Enumerations**

Any type which is an instance of **Enum** can be used in an arithmetic sequence, not just numbers:

```
alphabet :: String
alphabet = ['A' .. 'Z']
```

Including your own datatypes, just derive from Enum to get a default implementation:

```
data MyEnum = A | B | C deriving(Eq, Show, Enum)

main = do
    print $ [A ..]                 -- prints "[A,B,C]"
    print $ map fromEnum [A ..]    -- prints "[0,1,2]"
```

Comment: first time you see it, it's a surprise that `[A ..]` is in fact a finite enumeration.

Answer (score 3):

**Monads**

They are not that hidden, but they are simply everywhere, even where you don't think of them (Lists, Maybe-Types) ...

Comment: They really are and Monads, and the other type classes that surround them are so powerful that you would be a fool not to use them in every language you could. I believe that 'The Monad.Reader' Issue thirteen has a really good explanation of how it all comes together.