# Hidden features of Clojure

Tags: clojure

Which lesser-known but useful features of Clojure do you find yourselves using? Feel free to share little tricks and idioms, but try to restrict yourselves to Core and Contrib.

I found some really interesting information in answers to these similar questions:

- [Hidden features of Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211216/hidden-features-of-haskell)
- [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python)
- [Hidden features of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496/hidden-features-of-java)
- [Hidden features of C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132241/hidden-features-of-c)
- [Hidden features of Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161872)
- [Hidden features of Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998/hidden-features-of-ruby)

There are many more "Hidden feature" questions for other languages, so I thought it would be nice to have one for Clojure, too.

Answer (score 23):

Clojure has an immutable, persistent queue datatype, PersistentQueue, but it doesn't (yet?) have literal reader syntax or Clojure wrapper functions, so you have to create one via a Java call.  Queues conj (push) onto the rear and pop from the front with good performance.

```
user> (-> (clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY)
          (conj 1 2 3)
          pop)
(2 3)
```

Lists conj onto the front and pop from the front.  Vectors conj onto the rear and pop from the rear.  So queues are sometimes exactly what you need.

```
user> (-> ()
          (conj 1 2 3)
          pop)
(2 1)
user> (-> []
          (conj 1 2 3)
          pop)
[1 2]
```

Comment: WOW. popping 100000 items off a list my computer takes ~12ms. Converting the list to a queue AND popping everything off takes ~0.2. That's a huge help in the program I'm writing.

Answer (score 13):

```
(defn foo [a & [b c]] ...)
```

You can destructure the rest argument.

Update:

The latest commit to the git repo (29389970bcd41998359681d9a4a20ee391a1e07c) has made it possible to perform associative destructuring like so:

```
(defn foo [a & {b :b c :c}] ...)
```

The obvious use of this is for keyword arguments. Note that this approach prevents mixing keyword arguments with rest arguments (not that that's something one's likely to need very often).

```
(defn foo [a & {:keys [b c] :or {b "val1" c "val2"}] ...)
```

If you want default values for keyword arguments.

Answer (score 11):

The read-eval reader macro: `#=`

```
(read-string "#=(println \"hello\")")
```

This macro can present a security risk if `read` is used on user input (which is perhaps a bad idea on its own). You can turn this macro off by setting `*read-eval*` to `false`.

Answer (score 8):

You can `apply` functions to infinite argument sequences. For example

```
(apply concat (repeat '(1 2 3)))
```

produces a lazy sequence of 1,2,3,1,2,3... Of course for this to work the function also has to be lazy with respect to its argument list.

Comment: There is a better way of doing this 
(cycle '(1 2 3))

Comment: @nickik: Of course - `(repeat '(1 2 3))` was just meant as an example infinite sequence of sequences to show how `(apply concat ...)` works.

Answer (score 6):

From the increasingly good ClojureDocs site an idiom using `juxt`
http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/juxt

`;juxt is useful for forking result data to multiple termination functions
(->> "some text to print and save to a file"
  ((juxt
     println
     (partial  spit "useful information.txt"))))`