# How can I use the Clojurescript cljs.core.PersistentQueue queue?

Tags: clojurescript

I can't seem to find any documentation on the Clojurescript cljs.core.PersistentQueue. Should I be using it at all? Or should I be using another method of making a Clojurescript queue?

### Update

In the meantime I am using channels, `(<!, (>!` and go blocks and this seems to do the trick

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `PersistentQueue` is another persistent data structure with different behavior and performance characteristics when compared to list, vector, map, and set. If you look at the docstrings for `pop` and `peek`, for example, you will see this datatype being referred to as "queue".

Since it has no literal syntax, you have to start off by creating an empty one using `cljs.core.PersistentQueue/EMPTY`.

This post provides a good high-level summary of the Clojure equivalent  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2495105

Answer (score 17):

ClojureScript actually has a tagged literal `#queue []` for creating queues, which I found after putting Mike's answer into a [repl](https://github.com/shaunlebron/cljs-node-repl)

```
cljs.user=> cljs.core/PersistentQueue.EMPTY    
#queue []

cljs.user=> #queue []
#queue []

cljs.user=> (def q #queue [1 2 3])
#queue [1 2 3]

cljs.user=> (conj q 4)
#queue [1 2 3 4]

cljs.user=> (pop q)
#queue [2 3]

cljs.user=> (peek q)
1
```

Comment: Cool. I had not heard of this