# How to use Clojure's PersistentQueue?

Tags: clojure

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/2495105/261952 somebody claims it works like this:

```
(-> (clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY)
      (conj 1 2 3)
      pop)
(2 3)
```

However when I try this in my REPL, I get this result:

```
=> #object[clojure.lang.PersistentQueue 0x11f5966 "clojure.lang.PersistentQueue@402"]
```

Since that post is 7 years old, behaviour may have changed.
How cat I get it working today (Clojure 1.8)?

Comment: That's just an ugly (or default) `toString` implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It still works. Add `seq` to the threading to see what there is:

```
(-> (clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY)
    (conj 1 2 3)
    pop
    seq)
;(2 3)
```