# Polymorphic signature for non-polymorphic function: why not?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

As an example, consider the trivial function

```
f :: (Integral b) => a -> b
f x = 3 :: Int
```

GHC complains that it cannot deduce (b ~ Int). The definition matches the signature in the sense that it returns something that is Integral (namely an Int). Why would/should GHC force me to use a more specific type signature?

Thanks

Comment: This signature says that the function can return *any* `Integral` type, which is obviously not true.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Type variables in Haskell are universally quantified, so `Integral b => b` doesn't just mean *some* `Integral` type, it means *any* `Integral` type. In other words, the *caller* gets to pick which concrete types should be used. Therefore, it is obviously a type error for the function to always return an `Int` when the type signature says I should be able to choose any `Integral` type, e.g. `Integer` or `Word64`.

There are extensions which allow you to use [existentially quantified type variables](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_type), but they are more cumbersome to work with, since they require a wrapper type (in order to store the type class dictionary). Most of the time, it is best to avoid them. But if you did want to use existential types, it would look something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data SomeIntegral = forall a. Integral a => SomeIntegral a

f :: a -> SomeIntegral
f x = SomeIntegral (3 :: Int)
```

Code using this function would then have to be polymorphic enough to work with any `Integral` type. We also have to pattern match using `case` instead of `let` to keep GHC's brain from exploding.

```
> case f True of SomeIntegral x -> toInteger x
3
> :t toInteger
toInteger :: Integral a => a -> Integer
```

In the above example, you can think of `x` as having the type `exists b. Integral b => b`, i.e. some unknown `Integral` type.

Comment: Just in case, @hammar is referring to this funny error message when saying about "GHC's brain explosure" :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/213441/211906

Comment: Yes, but no no no to ever using existential quantifiaction like this.  The way to design this is not to: just have `f` return a plain old `Int` (or whatever concrete type is appropriate), which has more information than `Integral a => a`.  Abstraction boundaries should occur over function arguments, not results.

Answer (score 2):

The most general type of your function is

```
f :: a -> Int
```

With a type annotation, you can only demand that you want a *more* specific type, for example

```
f :: Bool -> Int
```

but you cannot declare a *less* specific type.
The Haskell type system does not allow you to make promises that are not warranted by your code.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, in Haskell if a function returns a result of type `x`, that means that the *caller* gets to decide what the actual type is. Not the function itself. In other words, the function must be able to return *any possible type* matching the signature.

This is different to most OOP languages, where a signature like this would mean that the *function* gets to choose what it returns. Apparently this confuses a few people...

Comment: It helps not to think of `f :: Foo a => Int -> a` as `Foo f(int);`, but as something more like `T f<T>(int) where T : Foo;` (using C# syntax).