# Odd ghc error message, "My brain just exploded"?

Tags: haskell, gadt, arrows

When I try to pattern-match a GADT in an `proc` syntax (with Netwire and Vinyl):

```
sceneRoot = proc inputs -> do
            let (Identity camera :& Identity children) = inputs 
            returnA -< (<*>) (map (rGet draw) children) . pure
```

I get the (rather odd) compiler error, from ghc-7.6.3

```
  My brain just exploded
    I can't handle pattern bindings for existential or GADT data constructors.
    Instead, use a case-expression, or do-notation, to unpack the constructor.
    In the pattern: Identity cam :& Identity childs
```

I get a similar error when I put the pattern in the `proc (...)` pattern. Why is this? Is it unsound, or just unimplemented?

Comment: There seems to be [some explanation in the source](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/17c955402871862dea5021e0b83b0949da5e51e7/compiler/typecheck/TcPat.lhs#L1012) near [where the error message is generated](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/17c955402871862dea5021e0b83b0949da5e51e7/compiler/typecheck/TcPat.lhs#L1118).

Comment: I think `->` should be `$`.

Comment: @bisserlis: No, it's [arrow syntax](http://www.haskell.org/arrows/syntax.html).

Comment: Oh fascinating! I've never seen this extension before. After a quick search, the [vinyl docs for Rec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl-0.3/docs/src/Data-Vinyl-Rec.html#Rec) indicate that `:&` was defined as a GADT data constructor. If you switch to using a case statement the problem should evaporate.

Comment: @icktoofay Copy some text from there to here and make it an answer!

Comment: @DanielWagner: I would, but I'm not sure I understand it myself, and I'm not comfortable posting an answer I can't explain.

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/213441/1651941

Answer (score 12):

Consider the GADT

```
data S a where
  S :: Show a => S a
```

and the execution of the code

```
foo :: S a -> a -> String
foo s x = case s of
            S -> show x
```

In a dictionary-based Haskell implementation, one would expect that the value `s` is carrying a class dictionary, and that the `case` extracts the `show` function from said dictionary so that `show x` can be performed.

If we execute

```
foo undefined (\x::Int -> 4::Int)
```

we get an exception. Operationally, this is expected, because we can not access the dictionary.
More in general, `case (undefined :: T) of K -> ...` is going to produce an error because it forces the evaluation of `undefined` (provided that `T` is not a `newtype`).

Consider now the code (let's pretend that this compiles)

```
bar :: S a -> a -> String
bar s x = let S = s in show x
```

and the execution of

```
bar undefined (\x::Int -> 4::Int)
```

What should this do? One might argue that it should generate the same exception as with `foo`. If this were the case, referential transparency would imply that

```
let S = undefined :: S (Int->Int) in show (\x::Int -> 4::Int)
```

fails as well with the same exception. This would mean that the `let` is evaluating the `undefined` expression, very unlike e.g.

```
let [] = undefined :: [Int] in 5
```

which evaluates to `5`.

Indeed, the patterns in a `let` are *lazy*: they do not force the evaluation of the expression, unlike `case`. This is why e.g.

```
let (x,y) = undefined :: (Int,Char) in 5
```

successfully evaluates to `5`.

One might want to make `let S = e in e'` evaluate `e` if a `show` is needed in `e'`, but it feels rather weird. Also, when evaluating `let S = e1 ; S = e2 in show ...` it would be unclear whether to evaluate `e1`, `e2`, or both.

GHC at the moment chooses to forbid all these cases with a simple rule: no lazy patterns when eliminating a GADT.

Comment: The last example (with multiple `let`s) is closer to the reason given in the ghc source.  The simple approach (from the typechecker's standpoint) is to combine all the constraints into a single context.  But in some cases that simplification is not valid.  So currently those cases are disallowed.