# Why do Haskell's scoped type variables not allow binding of type variables in pattern bindings?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I noticed that GHC's `ScopedTypeVariables` is able to bind type variables in function patterns but not let patterns.

As a minimal example, consider the type

```
data Foo where Foo :: Typeable a  => a -> Foo
```

If I want to gain access to the type inside a Foo, the following function does not compile:

```
fooType :: Foo -> TypeRep
fooType (Foo x) =
    let (_ :: a) = x
    in typeRep (Proxy::Proxy a)
```

But using this trick to move the type variable binding to a function call, it works without issue:

```
fooType (Foo x) =
    let helper (_ :: a) = typeRep (Proxy::Proxy a)
    in helper x
```

Since `let` bindings are actually function bindings in disguise, why aren't the above two code snippets equivalent?

(In this example, other solutions would be to create the `TypeRep` with `typeOf x`, or bind the variable directly as `x :: a` in the top-level function. Neither of those options are available in my real code, and using them doesn't answer the question.)

Comment: You don't need to explicitly introduce any type variable at all: `fooType (Foo x) = typeRep [x]` will also work, using the fact that the `proxy` for `typeRep` can be any functor: not necessarily the trivial `Proxy`, it can also be something that actually contains an `a` value!

Comment: @leftaroundabout if we're getting rid of the type variable, you can go even further and just say `fooType (Foo x) = typeOf x`.  I went ahead and assumed the real use case was something where having access to the type variable was the important part.

Comment: @Carl yeah, but it's perhaps not that commonly known that _any_ function with `proxy x` argument can also be called with a concrete container containing an actual `x` value.

Comment: Indeed, I realize I can use `typeOf` or other solutions in this case (see last paragraph of the question in parentheses), but in my real code that is not available. I need to get a Template Haskell `Type` by putting the type variable in a type quote. I also can't bind `a` directly in the top function, because the type I am trying to get is actually a functional dependency of the hidden type. The helper function solution works fine, I just don't really understand why.

Comment: `let` can not do that, since it uses lazy pattern matching, and that can not bring typeclass dictionaries in scope. This is the same issue of https://stackoverflow.com/a/23540431/3234959

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The big thing is, functions are `case` expressions in disguise, not `let` expressions.  `case` matching and `let` matching have different semantics.  This is also why you can't match a GADT constructor that does type refinement in a `let` expression.

The difference is that `case` matches evaluate the scrutinee before continuing, whereas `let` matches throw a thunk onto the heap that says "do this evaluation when the result is demanded". GHC doesn't know how to preserve locally-scoped types (like `a` in your example) across all the potential ways laziness may interact with them, so it just doesn't try. If locally-scoped types are involved, use a `case` expression such that laziness can't become a problem.

As for your code, `ScopedTypeVariables` actually provides you a far more succinct option:

```
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables, GADTs #-}

import Data.Typeable
import Data.Proxy

data Foo where
    Foo :: Typeable a => a -> Foo

fooType :: Foo -> TypeRep
fooType (Foo (x :: a)) = typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy a)
```

Comment: I can't use the provided solution in my code, but that explanation of case and let expressions does answer the question. It is a more elegant solution than using the helper function. Thanks!

Comment: Is STV even needed? `fooType (Foo x) = typeOf x` or `fooType (Foo x) = typeRep [x]` if you really want to use `typeRep` for some reason.